# Some Protractor tests are skipped

Tags: javascript, windows, protractor, automated-tests

When I launch `protractor conf.js` and this file needs to launch multiple spec files (like below), some of them are (randomly?) skipped. It works quite well when I run each spec separately.

```
  specs: [
    'tests/test-1-*.js',
    'tests/test-2-*.js',
    'tests/test-3-*.js'
  ],
```

What can I do to run all tests without any being skipped?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* this is happening, but if you need to be sure to run all your tests with the same stability than when you run them separately, then you can create a `bat` file (if you're using Windows) like this:

```
CALL protractor conf.js --specs='tests/test-1-*.js'
CALL protractor conf.js --specs='tests/test-2-*.js'
CALL protractor conf.js --specs='tests/test-3-*.js'
```

This will solve the problem until you find the root cause.