# Why are some Protractor tests skipped?

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

When I launch protractor conf.js and this file needs to launch multiple spec files (like below), some of them are (randomly?) skipped. It works quite well when I run each spec separately.

```
specs: [
  'tests/test-1-*.js',
  'tests/test-2-*.js',
  'tests/test-3-*.js'
],
```

I've found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840038/some-protractor-tests-are-skipped/65840039#65840039), but now I would like to know the root cause... Any idea?

Comment: works well for me

Comment: works well for me too which protractor version are you using

Comment: What indicates that it doesn't work

Comment: Last version. Some tests are randomly skipped just as if they didn't exist